# Is efficient state preparation possible for binary states?

Tags: state-preparation, encoding

#### Binary Vector Definition:

A vector where each entry has one of 2 possible values: $\{0, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{K}}\}$.
Where $K$ is the number of non zero entries.

### Question

Is there anything special about binary vectors that could make them efficiently prepared using Amplitude Encoding?

Comment: If you have a function defining your test, you could Hadamard each of the input qubits, evaluate this function in an ancilla register, measure the ancilla and post-select upon getting $|1\rangle$ In the ancilla.

Comment: Assuming I have the function defining the test, my question would be. Is there anything special about these states that would this process efficient? (i.e not requiring an exponential number of post-selections)

Comment: Well, if $K$ is exponential as well, then you have decent odds of post-selecting your state.  if $K$ is polynomial then I guess it depends perhaps on a lot of things.  For example if $K$ is two, then it's straightforward to prepare the CAT-state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|00\cdots 0\rangle+|11\cdots 1\rangle$.  For $K=n$ (the number of qubits), it's also pretty straightforward to prepare the generalized $W_n$ state. You might want to also check out [Grover-Rudolph's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0208112) on integrable distributions.

Comment: But, if your test function is too complicated and encodes the solution to some 3-SAT problem, for example, then it might be very difficult to prepare your state (as otherwise, you could be solving an NP-complete problem with a quantum computer).

Comment: I need to prepare completely arbitrary "binary states", K would have any value from 1 to 2^n. Thank you I will look into what this test function will look like and if it can be efficiently implementable.

Comment: For the Grover-Rudolph paper, I just went through this. I don't see how it can help, since I don't have an efficient function that can produce the entries of the vector (or their sum). I guess I can load the whole vector into 2^n qubits and that would be my (depth) efficient function. But I was hoping I can use less qubits than that.